# Pandas check if two columns can be considered the composite key of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A sample dataframe:

```
data = {
    "col_A": ["a","a","b","c"],
    "col_B": [1, 2, 2, 3],
    "col_C": ["demo", "demo", "demo", "demo"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Dataframe

```
col_A   col_B   col_C
a       1       demo
a       2       demo
b       2       demo
c       3       demo
```

I can easily check if all values in `col_A` are unique or not by `df['col_A'].is_unique`.
Is there any way to check for two columns i.e. something like `df['col_A', 'col_B'].is_unique`

If `col_A` and `col_B` are the composite key of the data frame or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set all columns that should be included in the composite key as index and then check for `is_unique` on the index.

```
df.set_index(['col_A', 'col_B']).index.is_unique

#True
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with [`Series.any()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html)

```
not df[['col_A', 'col_B']].duplicated().any()
```

Comment: Is there any difference between `df[['col_A', 'col_B']].duplicated().any()` and `df.duplicated(subset=['col_A', 'col_B']).any()`? in-terms of memory maybe.